# Does JXLS support array formulas?

Tags: jxls

I'm trying to process an array formula in my template:

```
{=INDEKS(F2:H2;MATCH(A1;F2:H2;0))}
```

But jxls renders it as an ordinary formula?

```
=INDEKS(F2:H2;MATCH(A1;F2:H2;0))
```

Which doesn't work.

It seems Apache POI supports array formulas since 3.13 (the version I'm using with jxls)

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of jxls-2.3.0 it does not support array formulas.

You can raise an enhancement request at [Jxls issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues?status=new&status=open) to request it.